# FTP: I don't get to connect Ftp File with SwithYard ERROR Failed to start service SwitchYardService: host must be specified and not empty

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

```
17:16:56,767 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."intercard-esb.jar".SwitchYardService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."intercard-esb.jar".SwitchYardService: org.switchyard.exception.SwitchYardException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host must be specified and not empty
    at org.switchyard.as7.extension.services.SwitchYardService.start(SwitchYardService.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
Caused by: org.switchyard.exception.SwitchYardException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host must be specified and not empty
    at org.switchyard.component.camel.common.handler.InboundHandler.<init>(InboundHandler.java:77)
    at org.switchyard.component.camel.common.deploy.BaseBindingActivator.createInboundHandler(BaseBindingActivator.java:71)
    at org.switchyard.component.camel.common.deploy.BaseBindingActivator.activateBinding(BaseBindingActivator.java:63)
    at org.switchyard.deploy.internal.Deployment.deployServiceBindings(Deployment.java:515)
    at org.switchyard.deploy.internal.Deployment.start(Deployment.java:141)
    at org.switchyard.as7.extension.deployment.SwitchYardDeployment.start(SwitchYardDeployment.java:106)
    at org.switchyard.as7.extension.services.SwitchYardService.start(SwitchYardService.java:78)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host must be specified and not empty
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notEmpty(ObjectHelper.java:319)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileEndpoint.afterPropertiesSet(RemoteFileEndpoint.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileEndpoint.createConsumer(RemoteFileEndpoint.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileEndpoint.createConsumer(RemoteFileEndpoint.java:34)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.EventDrivenConsumerRoute.addServices(EventDrivenConsumerRoute.java:65)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:133)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:1971)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:1899)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:1921)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteService(DefaultCamelContext.java:1803)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:724)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1779)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:666)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.addRouteDefinition(DefaultCamelContext.java:671)
    at org.switchyard.component.camel.common.handler.InboundHandler.<init>(InboundHandler.java:75)
    ... 11 more

17:16:56,790 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015951: Admin console
17:16:56,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "intercard-esb.jar" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"intercard-esb.jar\".SwitchYardService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"intercard-esb.jar\".SwitchYardService: org.switchyard.exception.SwitchYardException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host must be specified and not empty"}}
17:16:56,792 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 4281ms - Started 184 of 261 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
17:16:56,795 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016009: Stopping weld service for deployment intercard-esb.jar
17:16:56,806 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment intercard-esb.jar in 13ms
17:16:56,808 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."intercard-esb.jar".SwitchYardService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."intercard-esb.jar".SwitchYardService: org.switchyard.exception.SwitchYardException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host must be specified and not empty

17:16:56,812 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"intercard-esb.jar\".SwitchYardService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"intercard-esb.jar\".SwitchYardService: org.switchyard.exception.SwitchYardException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: host must be specified and not empty"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a polling consumer?  Typically this means that the URL you have specified has an error in it.  For example, in you are consuming from an FTP site, you could have be missing a slash like:

```
sftp://myhost.com:22somefolder
```

In this case above a slash is missing:

```
sftp://myhost.com:22/myfolder
```

What is the endpoint causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This specific problem might be due to multiple reasons.
Please check end point very carefully that there is no trailing space

sftp://my.host.com:22 /sftpdirectory  (There is space between port 22 and /sftpdirectory, please remove the sapce)
or
sftp://my.host.com :22/sftpdirectory (There is space between my.host.com and port 22 , please remove the sapce)

The possibility of having the above space due to trailing space in the value of configured property